# Jquery UI dialog background not growing when form loaded with ajax

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

When I load a form into a Jquery UI dialog, if the form is longer than the existing page, the background does not continue down the full length of the page.

If I use the resizer to shrink the dialog and then stretch it back again then the background stretches with it.

Just wondering if there is some kind of function I can call to refresh the background size after I've done the Ajax load?

UPDATE:  I think I've found the answer, by changing `.ui-widget-overlay` to `position:fixed` it seems to solve the problem, just wondering if it will have any dodgy side-effects?

Comment: Glad you've solved it yourself, but without any code it's hard to say if they'll be any dodgy side-effects.

Comment: I only changed the CSS from position: absolute to position: fixed, it seems to work peachy, but just wondering if there are any general issues in using position:fixed that I should look out for?